# Android java, как сделать смену background на каждом уровне

Tags: java, android

Как сделать так чтобы на каждом уровне был свой background?

Answer (score 1):

При старте уровня, в экземпляр класса с отрисовкой, передавайте в конструктор параметры background. И если способ рисования не меняется, значит достаточно использовать экземпляры одного и того же класса с соответствующими параметрами.